# How do you search for multiple words in commit messages?

Tags: git, grep

I tried to use

```
git log --grep -e "foo|bar"
```

but I just got a fatal error.

Comment: The simplest is usually multiple `--grep` options (see raina77ow's answer). You can also tell Git which regular expression syntax to use, via `--basic-regexp`, `--extended-regexp`, `--perl-regexp`, and the like.

Answer (score 22):

As mentioned in the [**docs**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---grepltpatterngt), it's possible to use several `--grep=[pattern]` options to extend search for multiple words/patterns. For example, this line:

```
git log --grep="foo" --grep="bar"
```

... finds the commits with messages including either `foo` or `bar`.

If you need to match only those containing *both* `foo` and `bar` instead, use `--all-match` option as well:

```
git log --grep="foo" --grep="bar" --all-match
```